# Existing sequence Postgres with JPA 2.1 and Spring 4.3

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I am configuring a database pointing entity that already exists

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "contacto_generator", sequenceName = "commons.contacto_sequence")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "contacto_generator")
private Long id;
```

I have the annotations as I was in the old application.

When I upgrade an entity is fine, but when I create a new entity, the sequence does not work well

The sequence "commons.contacto_sequence" is in the 509.

I even activated "show_sql" and run:

```
select nextval ('commons.contacto_sequence')
```

If I run it directly in the database, it goes perfectly

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: llave duplicada viola    restricciÃ³n de unicidad Â«pk_contactoÂ»
Detail: Ya existe la llave (id)=(459).
```

I do not know where the 459 value is, and no sequence in my database has that value

If you look at the console the name of the sequence appears with rare characters

I do not know what it can be or should change, because in theory is something that should automatically do Spring.

If it is because the annotations are deprecated and does not connect well to the sequence or that can be.

This project has Jpa 2.1, Spring 4.3.x

Comment: Use GenerationType.SEQUENCE strategy : @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contacto_generator")

Comment: As @adyjr said, you MUST use SEQUENCE strategy, because that is the ONLY way to guarantee that your sequence is used. Secondly perhaps if you looked at the SQL invoked and what is actually in your database you may find the answer (aka debugging). If it has a duplicate key then that key already exists in the entity table, so what is the sequence next_val ?

Comment: Databases have a data dictionary. A set of tables containing information about the database itself. This should include sequences. You should be able to use that to find all sequences and their current value.

Answer (score 0):

Try use GenerationType.SEQUENCE strategy:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "contacto_generator", sequenceName = "commons.contacto_sequence")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contacto_generator")
private Long id;
```

Comment: I put it that way, but it still makes the same mistake.